# In every instance where I receive a message from the other end of a socket, why is there a 'b' before every message?

Tags: python, sockets

For instance:

```
import socket

s.connect('123.456.78.9', '8080')
word = s.recv(1024)
word.decode()
print(word)
```

The output will be:

```
b'this is the string inside the word variable after receiving it from the other end'
```

is there anyway to get rid of the `b` at the start, and the quote marks around it?

Comment: Because the data is sent as bytes, not strings

Comment: `word.decode()` doesn't modify `word`, you need to assign it: `word = word.decode()`

Comment: `word.decode()` returns the decoded string, it does not modify the object in place

Answer (score 1):

The `b` prefix stands for bytes and you are seeing it because the data you receive from the socket is raw bytes. If your message happens to be bytes that are valid text, say ASCII or UTF-8 text, then you will see what looks like the string you expected but with the `b` prefix. Strings differ from bytes in that some representations of strings require multiple bytes (sometimes a fixed number, sometimes a variable number) per character (technically referred to as a "code point"). In order to convert to between bytes and strings, use:

**bytes to str**

```
my_string = b"hello I am a bytes literal".decode()
```

**str to bytes**

```
my_bytes = "hello I am a string literal".encode()
```

These functions `decode` and `encode` also take an optional `encoding` parameter with the default being 'utf-8', which is what you should use if you do not know what encodings are. If you get an error saying something about a decode error, you may need to specify the encoding.